# Remove admin account

Tags: macos, software

A colleague of mine just got his new MacBook Pro and he ran through the set-up process. But as it turns out, he got the wrong MacBook Pro, so now, he needs to completely erase the already present data and account...

How can he completely erase all the data including the admin account? He already tried to boot from the recovery disk and to boot with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. But all he gets is the new set-up assistant. He wants the MacBook Pro in its original state, so that when you open it you see the initial setup steps, and not the account he just created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He could format THEN REINSTALL the OS and power off before the initial setup.

Also there is a way to [force setup assistant to run](http://www.techkaki.com/2011/07/how-to-re-run-mac-os-x-registration-screen/) without reinstalling the system (some unix knowledge required and yes, this works in Lion):

Boot to single user mode

```
mount -uw
rm -rf /Library/Preferences/
rm -rf /Users/username
rm /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/username.plist
rm -rf /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
exit
```

(Note: replace username with whatever account short name you’ve created)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting and Reinstalling the computer and turning it off when the Admin account *Setup* pops up should do the trick.

Comment: Is this a guess or are you sure about this?

Comment: It may have changed with Lion, but I've done it a couple of times already.

Comment: And you format the computer by using Disk Utily on the Recovery Disk?

Comment: I haven't tried this specificaly with Lion, but I guess it has not changed. Either way, with Recovery Disk or with an image of Lion in a USB flash Drive, should work, as it has nothing to do with the installation itself, but with what happens next.

Comment: Reinstall is not equal to format!

Comment: My bad, everytime I install, I format, hence the *misunderstanding*.